# C++ namespace ambiguity

Tags: c++

I have both `::tensor::contract` and `::tensor::detail::contract`

```
#include "tensor/detail/contract.hpp"

namespace tensor {


    template<typename Alpha, class A, class B, typename Beta, class C>
    void contract(Alpha alpha, A a, B b, Beta beta, C c) {
        detail::contract(alpha, a, b, beta, c);
    }

    template<class A, class B, typename U = int>
    struct contract_expression :
        expression<contract_expression<A,B,U> >
    {
        template<typename T, class C>
        void evaluate(T alpha, T beta, expression<C> &c) const {
            contract(alpha*alpha_, a, b, beta, c); // ambiguity here
        };
    };
```

why do I get ambiguity in `contract_expression::evaluate`?  I am fairly certain there is no stray `using` directive.

error:

```
 ../../src/tensor/contract.hpp:12: note: candidates are: void tensor::contract(Alpha, A, B, Beta, C) [with Alpha = int, A = tensor::tensor_view<boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<d\
ouble, 2u>, boost::fusion::map<tensor::index<98, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<97, tensor::detail::index_range>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::voi\
d_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, B = tensor::tensor_view<boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<dou\
ble, 3ul>, boost::fusion::map<tensor::index<97, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<99, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<100, tensor::detail::index_range>, boost::fusion:\
:void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, Beta = int, C = tensor::tensor_view<boost::det\
ail::multi_array::multi_array_view<double, 3ul>, boost::fusion::map<tensor::index<98, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<99, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<100, tensor\
::detail::index_range>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >]
../../src/tensor/detail/contract.hpp:109: note:                 void tensor::detail::contract(Alpha, A, B, Beta, C) [with Alpha = int, A = tensor::tensor_view<boost::detail::multi_array::mu\
lti_array_view<double, 2u>, boost::fusion::map<tensor::index<98, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<97, tensor::detail::index_range>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, bo\
ost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, B = tensor::tensor_view<boost::detail::multi_array::mult\
i_array_view<double, 3ul>, boost::fusion::map<tensor::index<97, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<99, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<100, tensor::detail::index_range>\
, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, Beta = int, C = tensor::tensor\
_view<boost::detail::multi_array::multi_array_view<double, 3ul>, boost::fusion::map<tensor::index<98, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::index<99, tensor::detail::index_range>, tensor::i\
ndex<100, tensor::detail::index_range>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::vo\
id_> >]
```

Comment: What is the type of `alpha*alpha_`, `a`, `b`, `beta`, and `c`?

Comment: do you have somewhere a `using namespace ::tensor::detail` or something similar?

Comment: @GMan well, they are types in tensor namespace and alpha/beta are POD.

Comment: @aaa: My concern is if any of those are defined in the `detail` namespace, ADL will also look there.

Comment: You struct `contract_expression` inherits `expression< **contract_expression**<A,B,U> > ` :? Isn't this a problem, as it's incomplete type ?

Comment: @GMan - ok, i see.  does it matter if those types inherit from `detail` classes?

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: No, that's CRTP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @Thomas Edleson - Ah nice, thanks (:

Comment: @aaa: Yes, [here's a demo](http://ideone.com/FCahy). Thomas beat me to the answer though. :) Oh well. You can use `tensor::contract` to explicitly qualify it.

Comment: @GMan - thanks - i knew what to qualify but was curious what is happening exactly.

Comment: The `tensor::detail::index_range` template argument makes it use `contract` from the `detail` namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), associated namespaces are considered when resolving an unqualified function call.  At least one of the parameters on that line is associated with the detail namespace.

> ok, i see. does it matter if those types inherit from detail classes? – aaa

Yes, base classes are associated classes for the purposes of name lookup.  Functions in the namespaces of base classes are considered (§3.4.2/2, second bullet point).

If you want to force ::tensor::contract to be used, don't use an unqualified name:

```
::tensor::contract(alpha * alpha_, a, b, beta, c);
```

Or wrap the function name in parentheses, which disables ADL:

```
(contract)(alpha * alpha_, a, b, beta, c);
```

Comment: There was an interesting recent conversation about this being unexpected for someone else starting at about http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/364553#364553; this discussion is what alerted me to the issue of base classes in particular.

Answer (score 3):

Candidate number one there would be ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup, or Koening's lookup). Without seeing how those templates are instantiated it is hard to tell, but for the sake of argument, if one of the arguments to your function happens to be from within the `detail` namespace, then that namespace will be added to the lookup.

This is similar to something that you may be well used to:

```
namespace test {
   struct X {};
   std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, X const & ) {}
}
int main() {
   test::X x;
   std::cout << x; // [1]
}
```

At the line marked with [1], the code is in the global namespace, and yet it finds `operator<<` inside the `test` namespace. The reason is that `x` is an argument to that call, and the type is `test::X`, so the compiler looks up the `test` namespace.